# Does ES support to add a new item into the nested field of existing document?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a ES Doc like this.

```
{
  "title": "Nest eggs",
  "comments": [ 
{
  "name":    "John Smith",
  "comment": "Great article",
},
{
  "name":    "Alice White",
  "comment": "More like this please",
}
]
}
```

and now I'd like to add a new "comments" in this document and finially the document will be

```
{
   "title": "Nest eggs",
   "comments": [ 
{
  "name":    "John Smith",
  "comment": "Great article",
},
{
  "name":    "Alice White",
  "comment": "More like this please",
},
{
  "name":    "New guy",
  "comment": "something here",
}
]
}
```

I don't want to provide the existing "comments" object during every append so what should be the best approach to add a new object every time to this nested field.

My solution:

```
 POST test_v2/_update/Z_nM_2wBjkGOA-r6ArOb
 {
  "script": {
  "lang": "painless",
  "inline": "ctx._source.nested_field.add(params.object)",
  "params": {
     "object": {
        "model" : "tata nano",
        "value" : "2"
     }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: You can use script and update api as given in this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html

Comment: I implemented it using script just now but i am facing a issue that if my nested type is empty then this script fails with null pointer exception so how do i deal with that.

Comment: I have added my solution above plz have a look. Suggest me a approach to deal with this issue.

Comment: try  "scripted_upsert":true,"script": { <your_script>}

Comment: no it did not work, the issue remains the same.

Comment: solved it, by defining a empty body for my nested_field.

Comment: have added answer with field exist check in script field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for empty field in script itself. If field doesn't exist it is created first

```
 POST test3/_update/30RaAG0BY3127H1HaOEv
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "if(!ctx._source.containsKey('comments')){ctx._source['comments']=[]}ctx._source.comments.add(params.object)",
    "params": {
      "object": {
        "model": "tata nano",
        "value": "2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199060/discussion-on-answer-by-jaspreet-chahal-does-es-support-to-add-a-new-item-into-t).